# Reactjs - how can i take input from one component(inputbox) and use it in other component

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am building a MOVIE Search API app and I am taking input from one serah input box from the user  with help of following code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/Example.module.css";
import Appletv from "../appletv.json";
import Link from 'next/link';
export default class example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: "",
      filteredShows: Appletv.shows, // Starting with all shows
    };
    
  }
  
  
  handMoviesChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      movies: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const newFilteredShows = Appletv.shows.filter((show) => {
      return (
        this.state.movies === "" ||
        show.Title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.movies.toLowerCase())
      );
    });

    this.setState({ filteredShows: newFilteredShows });
  };

  render() {
    console.table(Appletv.shows);
   
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h3 className={styles.Title}>SearchTest</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         
         
          <div className={styles.row}>
            <input
              className={styles.input}
              id="search"
              type="input"
              required
              placeholder="Please enter title"
              value={this.state.movies}
              onChange={this.handMoviesChange}
            />
          </div>
        
           
         
          <Link href="/searchtest">
          <button className={styles.button} type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
          </Link>
        </form>
       
       
       <div  className={styles.results} >
            {this.state.filteredShows.map((filteredShows, index) => {
            return (
           <div>   
                  {/* <h1 className={styles.title}>{filteredShows.Title}</h1>  
                 <img
                    className={styles.image}
                    src={filteredShows.Thumbnail}
                    alt="Thumbnail"
                  />
                  <h5 className={styles.genre}>
                    {filteredShows.Genre} & {filteredShows["Release date"]}
                  </h5>
                  <p className={styles.desc}>{filteredShows.Description}</p>   */}
         </div>  
            );
          })}
       </div> 
      </div>
      
    );
  }
}
```

Output of this code is following
[image]
and I want to get those results in the second component and second component code is following

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import Appletv from "../appletv.json";
import Pagination from "./components/Pagination";
 /* import Netflixlogo from "../logos/netflix.png";
 *//* import Appletvlogo from "../logos/appletv.png";

import dstvlogo from "../logos/dstv.png";
import Amzonlogo from "../logos/amzon.png";
import Showmaxlogo from "../logos/showmax.png"; */

export default class searchtest extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: "",
      filteredShows: Appletv.shows, // Starting with all shows
    };
  }

  handMoviesChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      movies: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
/*     const filteredShows = array.slice(0, 6);
 */
    const newFilteredShows = Appletv.shows.filter((show) => {
      return (
        this.state.movies === "" ||
        show.Title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.movies.toLowerCase())
      );
    });

    this.setState({ filteredShows: newFilteredShows });
  };

  render() {
    console.table(Appletv.shows);

    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {/*         <h3 className={styles.Title}>SearchTest</h3>
         */}
        {/*         <h4 className={styles.searche}>Search Results</h4>
         */}{" "}
        <input
          className={styles.searchin}
          id="search"
          type="input"
          required
          placeholder="Please enter title"
          value={this.state.movies}
          onChange={this.handMoviesChange}
        />{" "}
        <button className={styles.searchbtn} type="submit">
          Search
        </button>{" "}
        <div className={styles.row}>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <h4>Filtering Options</h4>
              <label className={styles.label}>Movies</label>
              <input
                id="name"
                className={styles.checkbox}
                type="checkbox"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <label className={styles.label}>TV Show</label>
              <input id="name" className={styles.checkbox} type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <hr className={styles.hr} />
            {/*  <div className={styles.row}>
              <input
                className={styles.input}
                id="search"
                type="input"
                required
                placeholder="Please enter title"
                value={this.state.movies}
                onChange={this.handMoviesChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <input
                className={styles.input}
                type="text"
                list="genre"
                placeholder="Please Choose Genre"
              />
              <datalist id="genre">
                <option className={styles.option}>scifi</option>
                <option>Documentry</option>
              </datalist>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <input
                className={styles.input}
                id="name"
                type="input"
                placeholder="Season Input"
              />
            </div> */}
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <label className={styles.label}>Netflix</label>
              <input className={styles.checkbox} id="name" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <label className={styles.label}>Amazon Prime</label>
              <input className={styles.checkbox} id="name" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <label className={styles.label}>Apple TV+</label>
              <input
                className={styles.checkbox}
                id="name"
                type="checkbox"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <label className={styles.label}>Showmax</label>
              <input
                className={styles.checkbox}
                id="name"
                type="checkbox"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <label className={styles.label}>DSTV</label>
              <input
                className={styles.checkbox}
                id="name"
                type="checkbox"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <hr className={styles.hr} />

            <label for="cars" className={styles.label}>
              Select Year
            </label>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <select
                name="cars"
                id="cars"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                className={styles.dropdown}
              >
{/*                 <option value=""></option>
 */}                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                <option value="2021">2021</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <label for="cars" className={styles.label}>
              Select Genre
            </label>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <select
                name="cars"
                id="cars"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                className={styles.dropdown}
              >
{/*                 <option value=""></option>
 */}                <option value="SCIFI">SCIFI</option>
                <option value="comedy">COMEDY</option>
                <option value="ADVENTURE">ADVENTURE</option>
                <option value="DOCUMENTRY">DOCUMENTRY</option>
                
              </select>
            </div>
            <label for="cars" className={styles.label}>
              Select Age Restriction
            </label>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <select
                name="cars"
                id="cars"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                className={styles.dropdown}
              >
{/*                 <option value=""></option>
 */}                <option value="SCIFI">18+</option>
                <option value="comedy">Adult</option>
                <option value="ADVENTURE">Kids</option>
                <option value="DOCUMENTRY">Cartoons</option>
                
              </select>
            </div>

            <button className={styles.button} type="submit">
              Apply Filters
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        
        <div className={styles.results}>
          {/* here we are going to do conditional rendering like if netflix checkbox clicked then show or else not */}
     {/*  <img className={styles.condimg}
      src={""}
      alt="condren"
      /> */}

          <h4 className={styles.h2}>Search Results for {this.state.title}</h4>
          {this.state.filteredShows.slice(0,4).map((filteredShows, index) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <h1 className={styles.title}>{filteredShows.Title}</h1>
                <img
                  className={styles.image}
                  src={filteredShows.Thumbnail}
                  alt="Thumbnail"
                />
                <h5 className={styles.genre}>
                  {filteredShows.Genre} & {filteredShows["Release date"]}
                </h5>
                <p className={styles.desc}>{filteredShows.Description}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}

        </div>
         <Pagination/>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and output of the second component is like this
and can anyone help me for getting data from the first component to another second component I know we can do it with help of props and I am not getting how can I do that can anyone help me with this.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass state through React router

```
<Link 
    to={{ 
    pathname: '/pathname', 
    state: { results: 'this is results' } 
  }}
/>
```

In the component you can access the variable like this:

```
 componentDidMount: function() {
    var results= this.props.location.state.results
  },
```

hope it help :D

Answer (score 1):

You can add a prop (function) `onUpdate` to your search component, then call this function when you submit your search. On the parent-component, you can then add logic to pass it to your other component. For example, you add it to a state, which is then passed to your second component.

```js
handMoviesChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      movies: event.target.value,
    });
    this.props.onUpdate(event.target.value);
  };
```

Then in your parent component:

```js
<example onUpdate={(movies) => setState({ movies })} />
<searchtest movies={this.state.movies} />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you exaplain more about onUpdate and can I pass that parent component code in searchtest input value like this value={this.state.movies}
          onChange={this.handMoviesChange}
          onUpdate={(movies) => setState({ movies })}